# How to delegate subdomain to samba DC?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I set up a samba server and I'd like all the clients on my network to use the same DNS server.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRBys.png)

I have configured the servers (ubuntu/bind9:9.18-22.04_beta) as below.
I don't quite understand how to configure my zone so that I don't get any more errors.

```
NS1 LOG
10-Mar-2024 10:27:35.502 DNS format error from 10.3.0.9#53 resolving _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.wit.yooml.lan/SRV for 10.3.0.1#35268: non-improving referral
10-Mar-2024 10:27:35.502 FORMERR resolving '_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.wit.yooml.lan/SRV/IN': 10.3.0.9#53

NS2 LOG
10-Mar-2024 10:26:42.653 all zones loaded
10-Mar-2024 10:26:42.653 running
10-Mar-2024 10:26:52.649 resolver priming query complete: timed out
10-Mar-2024 10:26:52.649 managed-keys-zone/internal: Unable to fetch DNSKEY set '.': timed out
```

- 

```
#NS1 CONF
view "internal" {
        match-clients { 192.168.0.0/16; localhost; };

        dnssec-validation yes;
        recursion yes;

        forwarders {
                10.3.0.7; #AdGuard
        };

        zone "yooml.lan" {
                type forward;
                forward only;
                forwarders { 10.3.0.9; }; #NS2
        };
};
```

- 

```
#NS2 CONF
view "internal" {
        match-clients { 10.3.0.6/32; }; #NS1

        zone "yooml.lan" {
               type master;
               file "/etc/bind/db.yooml.lan";
               #dnssec-policy default;
               serial-update-method increment;
        };
};

$TTL 60
@       IN      SOA     ns2.yooml.lan. admin@yooml.lan. (2023081404 86400 3600 3600000 300)
        IN      NS      ns2.yooml.lan.

test    IN      A       192.168.0.1
wit     IN      NS      delta.wit.yooml.lan.
delta.wit.yooml.lan.   IN      A       10.3.0.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a recuser between the forwarder and the authority [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3KbF.png)

Comment: welcome, please remind to accept your own answer, else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem.